# Unknown class Un in Interface Builder file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I got this error during execution of a sample app:

> 2012-06-22 10:31:19.720 Health Beat[20283:f803] Unknown class Un in
>   Interface Builder file.

I do not understand where this error is coming from. As for the console:

```
2012-06-22 10:31:36.648 Health Beat[20283:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Change kind value 111485392 not
recognized'
*** First throw call stack:
(0....
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Check your `xib`s/`storyboards` (check inspector pane - field: 'custom class'). It seems that you have defined a custom class on a controller/view with the name `Un` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The app is loading a nib that contains a reference to a class named `Un` but there is no such class in your project.

Check the xib files in your project. You may have inadvertently changed some object's class to `Un` in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: I'll try right now: "Identity Inspector" is the key. Thank you